# Box shadows with html2canvas - installing build from git

Tags: reactjs, git, npm-install, html2canvas

The documentation for the main version of html2canvas says it does not currently support box shadows, but there are existing versions that do. This page showcases html2canvas working with box shadows [working box shadows](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/tests/)

I want to add this version to my project and tried

```
npm install --save https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas.git
```

which adds this line to my package.json file

```
"html2canvas": "git://https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas.git",
```

but when I try to import html2canvas with

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```

it gives the error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'html2canvas'
```

I've never used a library or npm package straight from git before - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try username/repository#branch in package.json

or try *npm install --save username/repo#branch-name*.
In your case *npm install niklasvh/html2canvas#master*.
Please let me know if it does not solve your problem.

Comment: Still doesn't import properly I'm afraid

Comment: Please try to delete your node_modules folder and install again. Then build might succeed.

Comment: Ok deleted node_modules and reinstalled - still no luck!

Comment: npm [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) has several methods. See if anyomne works for you.